# Deploying Rails App on heroku Get path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am deploying my rails app on heroku and i was facing an issue.

I get this error

> 2015-04-28T05:10:29.159894+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/welcome/index" host=still-dawn-6484.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=45bf4295-d7f0-4788-9f4d-be35cce41aa1 fwd="108.183.45.173"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=1754

My route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'welcome/index', to: 'welcome#index'
  post 'welcome/index', to: 'welcome#create'
  get 'welcome/new', to: 'welcome#new'


end
```

Comment: can you post your route file? I think you have not set `root 'welcome#index'`

Comment: sure i willl do it now gagan

Comment: @GaganGami i have posted it

Comment: It's saying status 500. Can you show your `welcome#index` code? Also, make sure you have ran your migrations

Comment: Have you check by running `rake routes`? Is this working in your development mode properly? I don't think so it should work on development. Check you have created your template for each method. Generally `Error 500` for `ActionView::MissingTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check you have created all templates for each method. Have you check your app works in local system in `development` mode? If it throw an error then first of all trace that error and fix. Then only try on `production`

Try to change your route file like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index' #to make it main page(default)
  post '/welcomes', to: 'welcome#create'
  get 'welcome/new', to: 'welcome#new'
end
```

Let me know it works for you or not? If you face any problem then let me know. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment i can let you know also would you have skype id? i have deadline and i am trying badly to deploy my app...i will definitely upvote your answer and any other ones .

Comment: added you. are you online

Comment: yes I m but it's better to ask here on stackoverflow as much as questions/queries you have. You can create new question post for each.

Comment: can u check my new question